# Error converting a Number to a String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do

`458.toString()` and its giving error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL). Then after trying/searching some other process they worked. eg.

1. `458 .toString();`
2. `458..toString();`
3. `(458).toString();`

I understand #3, but not well about #1 and #2. Please help me with explanation of #1 and #2 statement.

Comment: I'm using #3 now, never seen other two. So curious about them and their mechanism.

Comment: I've always liked `458 + ''`

Comment: I'm sure this has an explanation on SO, but in both cases JS mixes the notation dot with decimal point, space or an extra dot fixes the issue.